# Can I keep Entity Framework context as class variable?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm used to working the database connections where you connect/open/close as fast as possible in each method.  I'm now working with the Entity Framework and so my methods all do this type of thing:

```cs
using (var context = new FooEntities()) {
    // linq to sql query here
}
```

I've been told that with Entity Framework I can actually have that `context` variable be a class level variable and not have to instantiate it in each method.  Is that really the case, or should I continue this pattern in each method?

I'm using version 5.0.0 of the framework if that makes a difference.

Comment: Well it entirely depends on what you are doing, but it's still good advice to create the context as late as possible and kill it as soon as possible.

Comment: Is this MVC? [Here are 3 options](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). I prefer IoC with a base controller class.

Comment: @SteveGreene It's a Web Api 2 project, not MVC.

Comment: The major IoC's handle Web Api.

Comment: I'm looking at the ninject stuff that you pointed me at.  Unfortunately when I do the NuGet install the kernel config file that the docs say will get created doesn't get created.  I'll keep playing with it as this looks to be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are expecting it to act.  The only reason you'd want it to stick around is if you wanted to use the caching feature of DbContext across multiple method calls.  But since its pulling connections from the Pool anyway, disposing of a DbContext shouldn't really impact performance when creating a new one.

For me personally, I create the context as close as possible and kill it as soon as possible.  Thus, the Get calls should use AsNoTracking() to speed up the calls a lot if you don't care about trying to update them later.  You could also create a DbContextFactory so each class could control that interaction as it sees fit.  (i.e. Method A always creates a new one, but Methods B and C could share if either one called first).  Though, that could cause its own issues down the road, but then you can opt into those conditions.

Answer (score -1):

You can have Context as a property of a class, but you have to consider how to control the disposing of the Context. For example:

```
public class UnitOfWork:IDisposable
{
    public DbContext Context { get; set; }


    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        Context = null; //initialize context here
    }

    public void DoWorkWithContext1()
    {
        //anything you need
    }

    public void DoWorkWithContext2()
    {
        //anything you need
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Context != null)
            Context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then you'll use the class in this way:

```
     using (var unit= new UnitOfWork())
        {
            unit.DoWorkWithContext1();
            unit.DoWorkWithContext2();
        }
```

Comment: This is bad.  you set a property with the context, it is created externally from this Repository class.  That means the Repository don't control the creation of the context.  If the class doesn't control the creation of the context, you shouldn't be disposing it.  Anyone who uses the context outside of this repo will get an ObjectDisposedException.